# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.default.PropTypes.string') when i change react-native version that time it's give an error

Tags: react-native, typeerror

[metro server console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T94vJ.png) [Image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY7n5.jpg)

when I change react-native version that time it's give an error:
can anyone help me

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.default.PropTypes.string')

when i change react-native version that time it's give an error

***my package.json***

```
  "name": "*******",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.1.5",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.16.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^8.0.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^7.1.0",
    "d3-shape": "^3.1.0",
    "html-entities": "^2.3.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^3.3.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.67.2",
    "react-native-app-auth": "^6.4.3",
    "react-native-busy-indicator": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-camera-kit": "^12.0.0",
    "react-native-confetti": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-confetti-cannon": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.4.9",
    "react-native-fcm": "^16.2.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
    "react-native-img-cache": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-redux-i18n": "^1.0.11",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.12.0",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-form": "^8.3.8",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me which package you add in very last.....

Comment: also, attach a screenshot of your metro server console, this will give the exact file information.

Comment: this is actually propstype importing issue. in some package,s this importing from react-native or react instead of  props-types

Comment: I add "react-native-reanimated": "^2.4.1",

Comment: open your node module and go to react-native-reanimated folder and check index.js, import propsType from 'prop-types' instead of react-native

Comment: Hopefully, your error will be fixed

Comment: @Muhammad Momin, No problem